# Build a copula using Cramer's V

Tags: r, correlation, categorical-data, copula

I am trying to extract the dependence structure connecting some Categorical (CV), Ordinal (OV) and Interval (IV) variables ([definitions](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/whatstat/what-is-the-difference-between-categorical-ordinal-and-interval-variables/)). Basically, I am trying to build the structure into a copula, such that I can apply various marginals (mostly obtained from KDE), and create correlated samples. Here is my homework so far:

1. The obvious read about how to find the strength of association between CV, OV and IV (refs: [1](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/893/how-to-get-correlation-between-two-categorical-variable-and-a-categorical-variab), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108007/correlations-with-categorical-variables#), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119835/correlation-between-a-nominal-iv-and-a-continuous-dv-variable), [4](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/whatstat/))
2. A good and thorough read about copulas (refs: [5](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/copula/copula.pdf), [6](https://www.r-bloggers.com/modelling-dependence-with-copulas-in-r/), Parts I and II of [7](http://firsttimeprogrammer.blogspot.com/2016/03/how-to-fit-copula-model-in-r-heavily.html), [8](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v021i04/v21i04.pdf), [9](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387286594)) [I would recommend reference 7, 8 and 9 as a great starting point.]
3. Required relevant statistical background.

Now, I have come to the point where theory is transformed into practice, and I promptly got a little stuck and seek help. **I have the Cramer's V computed for all combinations of data. How do I use it to build the copula?** For example:

I have education categories, and employment industry. Education is OV, and employment is CV. The Cramer's V between them is 0.42. A list of some variables I have are: Age (IV), Education (OV), Employment (CV), Unemployment (CV), Disability (CV), Income (IV), Gender (CV), Nationality (CV), House Type (OV), ... And I have Cramer's V for all of them, pair-wise: Age (IV) and Education, Age and Employment, etc.

I can put them in a matrix similar to the correlation matrix, but I am a little doubtful if it functions the same way as a correlation matrix. According to this [QnA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140034/interpretation-of-cram%C3%A9rs-v), there is a difference between correlation and Cramer's V. If the Cramer's V matrix is analogous to a correlation matrix, my task is done. I will simply sample random continuous variables and preserve the Cramer's V in the form of correlation, build my copula, and then reverse it back using the marginal that best describes each of my variables.

However, (and this I feel strongly) Cramer's V is not analogous to correlation, although they both serve the same purpose. I may be wrong, hence I seek guidance. Also, if I am correct, how can I transform the Cramer's V matrix into a correlation matrix?

---

Ps. Please comment about the proposed technique to build a copula if you think it is incorrect (i.e. generating RV with the same correlation, and using it to build the copula).

Comment: In the study (Dissmann2013, doi:10.1016/j.csda.2012.08.010) the sampling from a copula based on a maximum spanning tree algorithm (MTS), Notice that an MST algorithm does not depend on the actual values of the edges, instead it only uses their rank.