# Cannot manually reproduce CCA loadings

Tags: python, multivariate-analysis, scikit-learn, canonical-correlation

For my current project I am using [`sklearn.cross_decomposition.CCA`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_decomposition.CCA.html). On several wepages (e.g. https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/canonical-correlation-analysis/ or https://www.uaq.mx/statsoft/stcanan.html or https://pure.uvt.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/596531/useofcaa_ab5.pdf) it says that canonical loadings can be computed as correlations between variables and the canonical variates. However, I could not reproduce this using `scipy.stats.pearsonr`? Is this just false information or am I doing something wrong?

Here's an example

```
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import CCA
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

# compute CCA
X = np.array([[0., 0., 1.], [1.,0.,0.], [2.,2.,2.], [3.,5.,4.]])
Y = np.array([[0.1, -0.2], [0.9, 1.1], [6.2, 5.9], [11.9, 12.3]])
cca = CCA(n_components=1)
cca.fit(X, Y)
X_c, Y_c = cca.transform(X, Y)

# obtain loadings for X variable set
x_loadings = cca.x_loadings_

print(f"The first variable has a loading of {x_loadings[0]} on the first canonical variate")

# try to manually calculate loadings using pearson correlation. 
r,_ = pearsonr(np.squeeze(X[:,0]),np.squeeze(X_c))

print(f"Correlation between first variable and first canonical variate: {r}")
```

which gives you:

```
The first variable has a loading of [0.61454275] on the first canonical variate
Correlation between first variable and first canonical variate: 0.9610851804703184
```

As you can see those numbers are totally different...

Comment: Computations of CCA, including the loadings, can be found in https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/77309/3277.

Answer (score 2):

CCA has inconsistent nomenclature; there are a few things that I saw being called loadings:

1. variable weights or parameters that multiply your data and create the canonical variates. Analogous to beta^hat in linear regression, or just weights machine learning algorithms. This is probably what sci-kit learn's cca.x_loadings_ is. You can check if X * x_loadings = X^hat to confirm this, or read the docs.
2. Pearson's correlation between your X variables and X canonical variates (vice versa for Y). IMO this one is correct, but don't be surprised to see other uses.
3. Pearson's correlation between your X variables and Y canonical variates (or vice versa), also called cross-loadings.
4. canonical variates themselves

Another possibility is that you just calculated it wrong by using columns instead of rows or the first row instead of the last row or something like that. I am not saying you did, but it's easy to make mistakes like that in similar problems

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Indeed user [rep_ho](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/53084/rep-ho) was right, I did something wrong by not standardizing the X matrix before doing the calculations.   Doing the following before calculating the correlation solved the problem:

```
from scipy.stats import zscore
X = zscore(X,ddof=1)
```

**Additional notes (not relevant for this thread)**:

Further referring to the **first point** of rep_ho's answer, `X_c` can be reproduced by multiplying the standardized feature matrix with `cca.x_weights`:

```
X_c = np.matmul(X,x_weights)
```

That means that `cca.x_weights` is what rep_ho is referring to as "variable weights or parameters".

Comment: I am happy that you solved it, but why would zscoring something change the correlation?

Comment: Very good question, maybe you have an answer for that?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry

Comment: Note that `X_c, Y_c = cca.transform(X, Y)`, I'm afraid `X_c_hand = np.matmul(X, cca.x_rotations_)` other than `X_c_hand = np.matmul(X, cca.x_weights_)` by hand?  You can check `X_c` and `X_c_hand`!