# What are F values of the canonical functions in discriminant analysis?

Tags: spss, discriminant-analysis

Recently, I read a paper ([Pell et al. 2009](http://www.academia.edu/2575940/Factors_in_the_recognition_of_vocally_expressed_emotions_A_comparison_of_four_languages)) in which the authors use Discriminant Analysis, and I quote:

> The discriminant analysis produced three significant canonical
>   functions (Function 1, F(18, 2130) = 164.81, p<0.0001; Function 2,
>   F(10, 1508) = 85.43, p<0.0001; Function 3, F(4, 755) =  22.93,
>   p<0.0001).

I didn't find anything associated with F values of canonical functions in the result of DA done by SPSS, and I cannot understand the F values of the canonical functions. Why are they reported, how are they computed?

Comment: SPSS and many other programs of discriminant analysis and canonical correlations (they are closely related) test canonical functions [by Wilk's lambda](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/74516/3277) which has approximately chi-square distribution. But the latter [is closely related to](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/chi-squared-and-f-distributions/) and can be recomptuted onto F distribution. So it is possible to use F.